# Queue in singleton object

Tags: python, queue, singleton

I'm using the singleton design pattern which holds a queue and look like that:

```
class MySingleton():
    __instance = None
    __msg_queue = None
    MAX_QUEUE_SIZE = 10000
    lock = threading.Lock()

    @staticmethod
    def get_instance():
        if not MySingleton.__instance:
            MySingleton.lock.acquire()
            if not MySingleton.__instance:
                MySingleton.__instance = MySingleton()
            MySingleton.lock.release()
        return MySingleton.__instance

    def __init__(self):
        self.__msg_queue = queue.Queue(maxsize=self.MAX_QUEUE_SIZE)

    def get_msg(self):
        return self.__msg_queue.get()

    def put_msg(self, msg):
        self.__msg_queue.put(msg)

    def is_empty(self):
        return self.__msg_queue.empty()
```

And when I try to use the is_empty method at another thread that way:

```
while True:
    if MySingleton.get_instance().is_empty():
        continue
    else:
        # do something
```

My code stuck. Can someone see the problem?

Comment: I assume you have code that's also inserting data into the queue?  Can we see that code?  If this is all you are running, then the infinite loop that does nothing makes sense.

Comment: Testing `is_empty` is not a safe way to use a synchronized queue. Whatever result you get when you call `is_empty`, that result may no longer be true by the time you call `get`.

Comment: @martineau He does create an instance in ``get_instance()``.  @user2357112: You don't see what he does when it's not empty.  He could do what he does in the ``get_instance()`` method and acquire the lock, and then do the check again.  So it seems a bit premature to say he's being unsafe when you don't even see his use of ``get``

Comment: You need to acquire the lock *before* checking ` MySingleton.__instance` at the very beginning of `get_instance()`. I also suggest that you use a `with` statement to acquire and automatically release the lock because it's shorter and more foolproof.

Comment: Yes I'm also inserting data into the queue at another thread using: 
'code' MySingleton.get_instance().put_msg(data)

Comment: While `Queue`s themselves *are* thread-safe, the separate attributes of your own class containing one are not (e.g. `__instance`) — so they need to be protected with their own mutex/lock.